# How should I manage the activity stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-menu

[image: Main Activity]

I have an app with a main menu at bottom; I can't figure out how should I manage the activity stack, because every button opens an activity, and each activity can start more activities, and i was looking for a management in the style of the current Instagram's app. It looks like (in the Instagram app) that every activity started by each button in the bottom menu opens a new activity stack, but when you press back button, it navigates in the reverse order you called every activity.

Sorry for my bad explanation, i hope that you can understand my aim.
You could check out Instagram Android app to figure out what is my goal.

My current implementation uses a MainActivity with a Fragment for the first menu button (Qui in giro->"Nearby"), but i probably should change this approach.
Thanks.

Comment: Instagram, if I'm not mistaken, uses 5 different images for each view, so that is 5 activities. Each view has a recyclerview than is being populated with cardviews.

Comment: If you post your code, people would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly you will have to decide what will be your main activity. 
2) Now use this main activity like as star topology. Means this main activity will be center activity. 
3) Use to  finish() method for finish back stack before receiving at this center activity. 
4) After it if you open another side of your main activity than you will see only new back stack will be displayed after pressing back button for receiving at main activity again.